# Excel VBA to copy and paste non english text in HTML/txt file

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am a developing a macro which will find the EN text and replace with FR text in HTML file. I have written below code. I want to replace "asthma tamed" with "l’asthmesous contrôle" but in HTML file it is showing output like this "l�asthmesous contr�le".

Note:- I cannot change any system settings.

```
Sub replacetext()

    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Dim strFileName, strOldText, RstrOldText, strNewText As String
    
    strFileName = ##### HTML File Path #####
    strOldText = "asthma tamed"
    MsgBox (strOldText)
    'RstrOldText = RemoveHTML(strOldText)
    'MsgBox (RstrOldText)
    strNewText = "l’asthmesous contrôle"
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)
    
    strText = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
    
    strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
    objFile.WriteLine strNewText
    objFile.Close
    
    MsgBox "Text Replaced !!!"
End Sub

Function RemoveHTML(text)
    Dim regexObject As Object
    Set regexObject = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regexObject
        .Pattern = "<!*[^<>]*>"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Format = "Unicode Text"
    End With

    RemoveHTML = regexObject.Replace(text, "")
End Function
```

Comment: I think this is an HTML problem. There doesn't seem to be a problem with your code. The issue is how the browser represents those "special" (in English) characters on the screen. You should edit your question to add the HTML tag.

Comment: I have noticed that when i replaced the text from EN to FR. Encoding format of the file is changing from UTF-8 to ANSI. Is there any way I can set file format to "UTF-8" after editing HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding \ before each special character? how about using  &‌ocirc; for the circumflex'd o and just ' for the ' or ' ?